# Nextjs - Reactjs - Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working with Nextjs and Reactjs. I have set the Layout.js file for my application UI.

I wonder why my console returns me:

> Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single
>   React element child.

Here's my layout.js :

```
export default ({ children, title = 'This is the default title' }) => (
    <div>
        <Head>
        <title>{ title }</title>
        <meta charSet='utf-8' />
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width' />
        </Head>
        <div className={style.layout}>
            <div>
                <div className={style.header}>
                    <div className= {style.headbar}> 
                        <div className={style.headerLeft}>
                            <Logo className={style.logo}/> 
                        </div>
                        <div className={style.headerRight}>
                            <MenuContainer className={style.menu}/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.chatbox}> 
                        <ChatContainer/>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                { children }

                <div className={style.footer}> 
                    <Link to="/quote" className={style.quote}> 
                        Click here
                    </Link>
                    <SocialMedia/>
                    <Subscription/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

My wrappedComponent.js:

```
const Index = () => (
      <Provider store={store}> 
            <Layout> 
                  <Home/>
            </Layout>
      </Provider>
)
```

I can't figure out  what is wrong, it seems to me everything is great, if someone have any hint, would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you write `<Link to="/quote/" className={style.quote}>Click here</Link>`? I.e. without any spaces inside the `Link` component children.

Comment: Thanks  Tholle, seems it's still doesn't works :/

Comment: Alright. If you check the stack trace in the browser, where does it say the error is coming from?

Comment: Seems it comes from "src/ui/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)"

Comment: Yes, that is the React specific code, but you should be able to see where in *your own code* it originated from.

Comment: hmm I see... It seems I have only path to node_modules files currently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112294/invariant-violation-react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-elem)

Comment: Hi Erik thanks for your answer. My code is wrapped inside a div pair but it doesnt works :/

Comment: seems NextJS accept only a specific layout methodology

Comment: How about Logo, MenuContainer, ChatContainer, SocialMedia, Subscription component. Do they return a single element? The error of React isn't strait-forward in this case, so you have to check all of them. Try removing one by one and see if the problem still existed. And you can find which one cause it.

Comment: One more possible problem could be <Link> component. Where do you import it from?

Comment: Okay I will double check, my Link component come from `import Link from 'next/link';`

Comment: I have double checked but seems all my components are good. My page works only when I delete all the boilerplate to maintain only the {children} component

Comment: So It should not be they Layout itself, but the components inside it. You should remove everything and add it again one by one until the error comes again. By doing that, you can find which component results error.

Comment: yeah I have done that but that works only when all the component are removed. It's a kind of ninja's error, but I will find the flaw x'p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my data structure corresponded to an another framework. So there was some tiny details that make NextJS crush - like "props" calls inside my React Links, this kind of stuff-. So if someone have the same problem, double check you framework data structure's configuration